# What the easiest way to see you own latest questions?

Tags: support, questions

When I add a question in SO I have a hard time finding them again. I most often just google them, but there must be a simple link from your accound that I have missed.

So, how do I find my own latest created questions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to your profile by clicking the name in the top right.

It will take you to activity page.

In the vertical middle of the page, you can see answers and questions in the left side with 3 options in the top to sort (under summary tab).

Choose Newest

[image]

[image]

Comment: nice freehand art but its a dupe :)